# How to Localize a Safari Extension?

Tags: localization, safari-extension

What's the best way to localize a Safari Extension?  I would like to get strings from a localized file to display in our toolbar dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does **not** make it easy. I did a pretty thorough search on [Apple's Safari Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/index.html) and there's nothing there that talks about "localize" or "localization", not even in the [Safari Extensions Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977). It may be that the localization scheme that Safari is using somewhat matches what can be found for Firefox or Chrome plugins.

In cases like this, developers are kind of on their own.  I'd recommend filing bugs (via http://bugreporter.apple.com ) for both documentation to be added to the Safari Extension development guides and also something more obvious to be added to the Extension Builder built into Safari.

If this were my problem, I'd approach this by looking at other open source Safari plugins that do have support for multiple languages.  For example, "ClickToPlugin" Safari Extension on GitHub has a [localization.js file](https://github.com/hoyois/clicktoplugin/blob/master/ClickToPlugin.safariextension/localization.js) which affects the [Settings](https://github.com/hoyois/clicktoplugin/blob/ff9e5be2f2df7efb612568829f2de5934e6fd579/ClickToPlugin.safariextension/settings.html) and the menu items in the [Global js](https://github.com/hoyois/clicktoplugin/blob/64f71e9f3ae3d6bb974ed3d11563f9374be3c7d3/ClickToPlugin.safariextension/global.js) file.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if there was an official method now.